# How to call a method from a service to a controller Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Ionic so I need a little help, all I want is to make a service and its methods can be called in different controllers!
By the way, the service code works fine when I had it on the controller page!

Here's the service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
// import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Facebook } from '@ionic-native/facebook/ngx';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LogInOutService {
  providerFb: firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider;
  connected=false;
  userId: any;
  constructor(public afDB: AngularFireDatabase,
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private fb: Facebook,
    public router:Router,
    public platform: Platform) {this.providerFb = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
      this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(auth=>{
        console.log(auth);
        if(!auth){
            console.log('Non Connecté');
        } else{
            console.log('Utilisateur connecté: '+ auth.uid);
            this.connected=true;
        }
      }); }

      
      facebookLogin() {
        if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
          console.log('PLateforme cordova');
          this.facebookCordova();
        } else {
          console.log('PLateforme Web');
          this.facebookWeb();
        }
      }
  
      facebookCordova() {
        this.fb.login(['email']).then( (response) => {
            const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider
                .credential(response.authResponse.accessToken);
            firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential)
            .then((success) => {
                //console.log('Info Facebook: ' + JSON.stringify(success));
                this.afDB.object('Users/' + success.user.uid).set({
                  displayName: success.user.displayName,
                  photoURL: success.user.photoURL
                });
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log('Erreur: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            });
        }).catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
      }
  
      facebookWeb() {
        firebase.auth()
          .signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider())
          .then((success) => {
            //console.log('Info Facebook: ' + JSON.stringify(success));
            console.log('Firebase success: ' + JSON.stringify(success));
                console.log('UserID: ' + success.user.uid);
                console.log('displayName: ' + success.user.displayName);
                console.log('photoURL: ' + success.user.photoURL);
                this.afDB.object('Users/' + success.user.uid).set({
                  displayName: success.user.displayName,
                  photoURL: success.user.photoURL
                });
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/chat-room');
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.log('Erreur: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
          });
      }
}
```

And here's what the controller contains, I injected the service and made that method call but nothing has worked and the console shows some errors like **"this.LogInOut.facebookLogin is not a function"**

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
// import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Facebook } from '@ionic-native/facebook/ngx';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LogInOutService } from '../log-in-out.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor( public LogInOut:LogInOutService) { 
    }

    lognow(){
      this.LogInOut.facebookLogin();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Did you import this service in app module or page module ?

Comment: import { LogInOutService } from './../log-in-out.service'; try this

Comment: Thanks for your comments it's really appreciated, but I've changed nothing and now it works fine, even though I've reserved couple times